# Why does every worker node correspond to different master session using data parallelism in the tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, distributed

When starting a distributed tensorflow program(refer to official **imagenet_distributed_train**), every worker node correspond to different master from the log. I start 2 worker nodes and 1 ps node, and got the log below:

```
worker 0 : Start master session 0ea38069210dd3af with config: allow_soft_placement: true

worker 1 : Start master session adf82dd63a6f4dc6 with config: allow_soft_placement: true
```

But I see below picture from tensorflow paper. In my limited experience with tensorflow, this should be in-graph model that one master corresponds to multiple worker.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4nEA.png)

My question is :

1. Data parallelism corresponds to between-graph model, and model parallelism corresponds to in-graph model. Is it correct ?
2. If yes, Do N worker nodes correspond to N master session in the data parallelism? If also yes, I don't understand why this is not one master session which controls multiple worker nodes. If one master corresponds to multiple worker, so why does above log show different master session ?

Thanks in advance